# Segue Programmatically

Tags: segue

Making fetch request and getting value from core data.  Based upon value F or M I would like to segue to a VC.  It keeps crashing on App Delegate.  I am using a tab bar controller to click on VC that does calculation and then should segue to appropriate VC.

```
func makeSegue() {

    print("\(meetGenderText.text!)")

    if (meetGenderText.text == "F") {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoreFemale") as! ScoreMeetFemaleVC

        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("scoreFemale", sender: nil)

    } else {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoreMale") as! ScoreMeetFemaleVC

        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("scoreMale", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `self.presentViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use both `presentViewController` and `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  If you want to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` be sure the segue exist in storyboard and starts at the `UIViewController` in which you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  Also ensure that the identifier in your code matches the segues identifier in storyboard.